# Icon composer stuffing up small images

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, icon-composer

For some reason, Icon Composer doesn't like my 32x and 64x icons.

[image: Icon not working]

They look fine as PNGs, but when put into Icon Composer and turned into a .ICNS file, the small images look stretched (the I is usually in the center).

[image: Icon fine as PNG]

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Have you tried iconutil, which is included in Xcode 4.4 in later? Icon Composer is effectively deprecated now.

Comment: Oh, good point :). Sorry, I haven't done any Mac development in a year or so, and didn't check. Thanks!

Comment: Just asking because I was curious if iconutil exhibited the same problem. I wish they hadn't gotten rid of it, myself, but iconutil presumably doesn't have the same bugs.

Comment: In my experience, opening and re-saving the PNG file in Preview solves the problem.